# SMS unicode using PHP

Tags: php, unicode, sms

I am using clickatell HTML API to send messages. Everything is working except the unicode conversion.

I need this "É" to be "00c9". Is there any converter in PHP that converts all characters to this unicode for SMS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work as requestied:

```
$var='É';

function utf8_to_unicode_codepoints($text) {
     return ''.implode(unpack('H*', iconv("UTF-8", "UCS-2BE", $text)));
 }

echo utf8_to_unicode_codepoints($var); //00c9
```

Comment: it worked PERFECTLY. I don't understand the theory behind it but just do the job. Thanks a lot Dagon.